# How to identify on what part of the image the mouse cursor is clicked in Python (cross-platform)?

Tags: python, user-interface

I am writing a program where the user will be shown a picture of a human face. When the user clicks on the certain part of the face, the program should write the name of this part (for example, "nose"). The program does **not** involve any AI/ML algorithms, I have to specify the names of each parts of the face on the image. I first thought of naming the face parts using pixels, but I assume it will likely be different for different platforms or devices. I then thought of using relative distances (e.g. 1/3 of the x-axis and 1/4 of the y-axis of the image), but it was tedious to do so because of specific problems. So is there a better way to do it?

Comment: cross platform? Tkinter (tee-kay-inter). comes with python.

Comment: If you have an 800x600 image and you display it at 800x600, then the pixel locations will always be the same.  However, if you're going to scale the image based on screen resolution, then you'll need to use scaling.  It's not as tedious as you suggest.  Consider using "virtual" axes of 1000x1000.  Just a couple of coordinate conversion routines, and there you are.